# Перехват вывода консоли python

Tags: python, консоль, linux

Есть некое консольное приложение **Linux**, например **top**. Надо скриптом **python** вытащить от туда некоторые строки. Такое возможно? Как это реализовать?
Подкиньте идей, а то что-то вообще не могу понять как это.

Comment: google:// subprocess popen pipe

Comment: какого мой полноценный ответ сделали комментом?

Comment: В ответах уже расписали о пайпе. Советую добавить при запуске `top` ключик `-b`, дополнительные симводы (грязь) выводиться не будут.

Можете попроблвать `top -b | less`

А еще читайте `man top`.

Comment: это "уже" произошло после того как мой ответ переместили в коммент :)

Comment: Подскажите, а есть идеи, как это сделать, если у меня открыто несколько консолей, и мне надо со всех считывать информацию одновременно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys

# using command top
a = 'top -n 1'

b = os.popen(a,'r',1)

print b
```

Ну или как-то так. b - файловый объект, буферизация по строчкам (см. параметр popen)

Comment: в строке 
  # !/usr/bin/python
надо убрать пробел перед восклицательным знаком, а то вся эта конструкция становится обычным комментарием

Comment: Ох, ну простите, опечатлся ))))))))

Answer (score 3):

```
top -n 1 | ./script.py
```

а в самом скрипте пишем:

```
import sys
data = sys.stdin.read()
```

и вывод команды оказывается в переменной

Comment: какой тип данных будет у переменной data ???

Comment: Строка, конечно, как же ещё. Другой вопрос, что конкретно top пишет ещё и различные нечитаемые символы (например, для отображения цвета), что тоже стоит учитывать при парсинге.

Answer (score 0):

Я надеюсь, эта строка вам поможет

```
 top -n 1 > /tmp/out.txt && cat /tmp/out.txt
```

Comment: Я надеялся обойтись без файлов... хотя тоже идея спасибо. Тогда надо прикрутить многопоточность. В одном будет постоянно выводить в файл с определенным интервалом времени, а в другом будет парсить результат. Как вам такое?

Comment: Файл не нужен)) поток читайте